# Does MySQL cache previous parts of queries?

Tags: mysql, caching, select

I have a query that goes something like this:

```
SELECT t1, t2,
IF(MATCH(t2) AGAINST ('input*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 10, 0) AS matches,
IF(t2 LIKE '%input%', 2, 0) AS similar
FROM tbl
WHERE t2 LIKE '%input%'
ORDER BY (matches + similar) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The query works fine, but the part I'm concerned about is whether or not MySQL is checking whether t2 is LIKE '%input%' twice, or if it caches the first result (which would be cool!).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it does not.

As a poor man's test, consider:

```
delimiter //
create function qqq() 
returns int no sql 
begin 
  set @x:=@x+1; 
  return 17; 
end //
delimiter ;

set @x := 0;
select qqq(), qqq(), qqq() > 1, qqq() > 1 from dual;
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| qqq() | qqq() | qqq() > 1 | qqq() > 1 |
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|    17 |    17 |         1 |         1 |
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+

select @x;
+------+
| @x   |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
```

While one can argue that this is a special case, since we're invoking a stored routine, as opposed to built-in function, there is no difference at the moment. Everything is re-evaluated.

This may change in the future -- there's nothing to strictly *prevent* this optimization from happening on well known, deterministic functions. But sometimes this may be hard to diagnose by the optimizer.

Comment: Very interesting - if not a little disappointing, heh. Maybe I'll find a better way of doing the query in the future, although for now, the dual LIKE comparator seems to be doing its job fast /enough/. It's for a search suggestions box and the response is instant.

Comment: But, I don't understand the need for this: `IF(t2 LIKE '%input%', 2, 0)` will **always** be **2** in your query, since you filter rows by that condition!

Comment: Yes, admittedly that was a rather bad example. It's not the exact query I'm making, I just thought of that on the spot.